# How do I extract patterns from lists of POS tagged words? NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, pos-tagger

I have a text file that contains multiple lists; each list contains tuples of word/pos-tag pairs, like so:

```
    [('reviewtext', 'IN'), ('this', 'DT'), ('movie', 'NN'), ('was', 'VBD'), ('great', 'JJ'), ('and', 'CC'), ('fun', 'NN'), ('i', 'PRP'), ('really', 'RB'), ('enjoyed', 'VBD'), ('this', 'DT'), ('awesome', 'NN'), ('movie', 'NN')]
    [('reviewtext', 'IN'), ('it', 'PRP'), ('was', 'VBD'), ('fun', 'VBN'), ('but', 'CC'), ('long', 'RB')]
    [('reviewtext', 'IN'), ('i', 'PRP'), ('loved', 'VBD'), ('the', 'DT'), ('new', 'JJ'), ('movie', 'NN'), ('my', 'PRP$'), ('brother', 'NN'), ('got', 'VBD'), ('sad', 'JJ'), ('and', 'CC'), ('unhappy', 'JJ'), ('at', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('end', 'NN')]
```

I need to extract all adjective-conjunction-adjective pairs, or all JJ-CC-JJ pairs (the words only, and not the pos tags). For this example, the final output should be a list containing all the patterns:

```
    ['great and fun', 'sad and unhappy']
```

I used the following code to tag the text:

```
    with open("C:\\Users\\M\\Desktop\\sample dataset.txt") as fileobject:
        for line in fileobject:
            line = line.lower() #lowercase
            line = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','',line) #remove punctuation
            line = nltk.word_tokenize(line) #tokenize
            line = nltk.pos_tag(line) #POS tag

            fo = open("C:\\Users\\M\\Desktop\\movies1_complete.txt", "a")
            fo.write(str(line))
            fo.write("\n")
            fo.close()
```

But how do I extract the words in the above mentioned patters? I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29073796/retrieving-tags-from-result-of-pos-tagging) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27045684/extracting-sentences-from-pos-tagged-corpus-with-certain-word-tag-combos), but they do not explain how to extract specific pos patterns. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless your files are in one-sentence-per-line format, this will give you poor results. Read entire paragaphs (or the whole file), break them up into sentences with `nltk.sent_tokenize`, and then process each resulting sentence with `nltk.word_tokenize`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from itertools import islice

for sub in l:
    for a, b, c in zip(islice(sub, 0, None), islice(sub, 1, None), islice(sub, 2, None)):
        if all((a[-1] == "JJ", b[-1] == "CC", c[-1] == "JJ")):
            print("{} {} {}".format(a[0], b[0], c[0]))
```

Which outputs `sad and unhappy`,  it does not include `'great and fun'` as that does not match the pattern `JJ-CC-JJ`.

Or just using enumerate and a generator:

```
l = [[('reviewtext', 'IN'), ('this', 'DT'), ('movie', 'NN'), ('was', 'VBD'), ('great', 'JJ'), ('and', 'CC'),
      ('fun', 'NN'), ('i', 'PRP'), ('really', 'RB'), ('enjoyed', 'VBD'), ('this', 'DT'), ('awesome', 'NN'),
      ('movie', 'NN')],
     [('reviewtext', 'IN'), ('it', 'PRP'), ('was', 'VBD'), ('fun', 'VBN'), ('but', 'CC'), ('long', 'RB')],
     [('reviewtext', 'IN'), ('i', 'PRP'), ('loved', 'VBD'), ('the', 'DT'), ('new', 'JJ'), ('movie', 'NN'), ('my', 'PRP$'), ('brother', 'NN'), ('got', 'VBD'), ('sad', 'JJ'), ('and', 'CC'), ('unhappy', 'JJ'), ('at', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('end', 'NN')]]

def match(l,p1,p2,p3):
    for sub in l:
        # avoid index error and catch last three elements
        end = len(sub) - 1
        for ind, (a, b) in enumerate(sub, 1):
            if ind == end:
                break
            if b == p1 and sub[ind][1] == p2 and sub[ind + 1][1] == p3:
                yield ("{} {} {}".format(a, sub[ind][0], sub[ind + 1][0]))

print(list(match(l,"JJ","CC","JJ")))
```

Output (based on example):

```
['sad and unhappy']
```

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "does not match JJ-CC-JJ" on the last line though? @padraic cunningham

Comment: @modarwish, your expected outputs shows `'great and fun'`, that does not match JJ-CC-JJ, it is JJ-CC-NN

Answer (score 2):

Even though the answer has been accepted (with a great answer) I think you will find this useful. You can use the following [library](https://github.com/machinalis/refo) to check for regular expressions in stream of objects.

```
from refo import finditer, Predicate, Plus

class Word(object):
    def __init__(self, token, pos):
        self.token = token
        self.pos = pos

class W(Predicate):
    def __init__(self, token=".*", pos=".*"):
        self.token = re.compile(token + "$")
        self.pos = re.compile(pos + "$")
        super(W, self).__init__(self.match)

    def match(self, word):
        m1 = self.token.match(word.token)
        m2 = self.pos.match(word.pos)
        return m1 and m2


originals = [
    [('reviewtext', 'IN'), ('this', 'DT'), ('movie', 'NN'), ('was', 'VBD'), 
     ('great', 'JJ'), ('and', 'CC'), ('fun', 'NN'), ('i', 'PRP'), 
     ('really', 'RB'), ('enjoyed', 'VBD'), ('this', 'DT'), 
     ('awesome', 'NN'), ('movie', 'NN')],
    [('reviewtext', 'IN'), ('it', 'PRP'), 
     ('was', 'VBD'), ('fun', 'VBN'), ('but', 'CC'), ('long', 'RB')],
    [('reviewtext', 'IN'), ('i', 'PRP'), ('loved', 'VBD'), ('the', 'DT'), 
     ('new', 'JJ'), ('movie', 'NN'), ('my', 'PRP$'), ('brother', 'NN'), 
     ('got', 'VBD'), ('sad', 'JJ'), ('and', 'CC'), ('unhappy', 'JJ'), 
     ('at', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('end', 'NN')]]


sentences = [[Word(*x) for x in original] for original in originals]
```

This is the interesting bit which says look for the sequence of objects where the `pos` attributes are `JJ` followed by `CC` followed by `JJ` or `NN`.

```
pred = W(pos="JJ") + W(pos="CC") + (W(pos="JJ") | W(pos="NN"))
for k, s in enumerate(sentences):
    for match in finditer(pred, s):
        x, y = match.span()   # the match spans x to y inside the sentence s
        print originals[k][x:y]
```

Output:

```
[('great', 'JJ'), ('and', 'CC'), ('fun', 'NN')]
[('sad', 'JJ'), ('and', 'CC'), ('unhappy', 'JJ')]
```

Comment: Quite interesting! I will give this a go as well.. How can I output only the words, and not the pos tags? E.g., ['great and fun', 'sad and unhappy'] @Ale

Comment: `" ".join([w for w, tag in originals[k][x:y]])` extract the word component from each `tuple` and put it on a list and join it with spaces. (didn't test this)

Comment: [spaCy](https://spacy.io/usage/examples#phrase-matcher) has a similar module for accomplishing object (POS and/or word) pattern matching to extract phrases. It's like regular expressions for words or POS tags instead of characters. Alternatively, spaCy also has a POS tag pattern [matcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32399299)

Comment: The link above for the 2nd POS tag matcher should be: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42887388/623735