# POS pattern mining with spacy

Tags: python-3.x, spacy

I am trying linguistic feature extraction from text using spacy in python 3. My input looks like this

```
Sent_id Text
1   I am exploring text analytics using spacy
2   amazing spacy is going to help me
```

I am looking for an output like this by extracting words as trigram/bigram phrases with a particular POS pattern supplied by me. like NOUN VERB NOUN,ADJ NOUN etc. and retaining the dataframe structure as well. if there are multiple phrases from one sentence then the record has to be duplicated with the new phrase.

```
Sent_id Text    Feature Pattern
1   I am exploring text analytics using spacy   exploring text analytics    VERB NOUN NOUN
1   I am exploring text analytics using spacy   analytics using spacy   NOUN VERB NOUN
2   amazing spacy is going to help me   amazing spacy   ADJ NOUN
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Code is explained in the comments

```
import spacy
import pandas as pd
import re

# Load spacy model once and reuse 
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

# The dataframe with text
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Sent_id': [1,2],
        'Text': [ "I am exploring text analytics using spacy", "amazing spacy is going to help me"]
    }) 

# Patters we are intrested in 
patterns = ["VERB NOUN", "NOUN VERB NOUN"]

# Convert each pattern into regular expression
re_patterns = [" ".join(["(\w+)_!"+pos for pos in p.split()]) for p in patterns]


def extract(nlp, text, patterns, re_patterns):
    """Extracts the pieces in text maching the POS pattern in patterns

    args:
        nlp : Loaded Spicy model object
        text: The input text
        patterns: The list of patters to be searched
        re_patterns: The patterns converted into regex

    returns: A list of tuples of form (t,p) where 
    t is the part of text matching the pattern p in patterns
    """
    doc = nlp(text)   
    matches = list()
    text_pos = " ".join([token.text+"_!"+token.pos_ for token in doc])
    for i, pattern in enumerate(re_patterns):
        for result in re.findall(pattern, text_pos):
            matches.append([" ".join(result), patterns[i]])
    return matches

# Test it 
print (extract(nlp, "A sleeping cat and walking dog", patterns, re_patterns))
# Returns
# [['sleeping cat', 'VERB NOUN'], ['walking dog', 'VERB NOUN']]

# Extract the matched patterns
df['matches'] = df['Text'].apply(lambda x: extract(nlp,x,patterns,re_patterns))


# Convert the list of tuples into rows
df = df.matches.apply(pd.Series).merge(df, right_index = True, left_index = True).drop(["matches"], axis = 1)\
.melt(id_vars = ['Sent_id', 'Text'], value_name = "matches").drop("variable", axis = 1)

# Add the matched text and matched patterns into new columns
df[['matched_text','matched_pattern']]= df.matches.apply(pd.Series)

# Drop the column and cleanup
df = df.drop("matches", axis = 1).sort_values('Sent_id')
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset =["matched_text", "matched_pattern"], keep='last')
```

#### Output:

```
    Sent_id     Text                                matched_text    matched_pattern
0   1   I am exploring text analytics using spacy   exploring text  VERB NOUN
2   1   I am exploring text analytics using spacy   using spacy     VERB NOUN
4   1   I am exploring text analytics using spacy   analytics using spacy   NOUN VERB NOUN
1   2   amazing spacy is going to help me           NaN              NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

`spacy` has a powerful pattern-matching language built-in: [spaCy docs](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching) and an [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42887388/623735) for a similar question.

That way you don't have to mash together regexes and POS tags like @mujjiga did in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55397291/623735).

So your example would look like this:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

examples = [
    "I am exploring text analytics using spacy",
    "amazing spacy is going to help me",
    ]
patterns = [
    [{'POS': 'NOUN'}, {'POS': 'VERB'}, {'POS': 'NOUN'}],
    [{'POS': 'VERB'}, {'POS': 'NOUN'}],
    ]
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add("noun-verb-noun", None, patterns[0])
matcher.add("verb-noun", None, patterns[1])
for text in examples:
    doc = nlp(text)
    matches = matcher(doc)
    for match_id, start, end in matches:
        string_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]
        span = doc[start:end]
        print(string_id, start, end, span.text)
```

Which prints out 3 matches, string_id's (pattern label), and their spans (start and end word positions):

```
verb-noun 2 4 exploring text
noun-verb-noun 4 7 analytics using spacy
verb-noun 5 7 using spacy
```

Comment: @Christopher, doesn't `span.text` on the last line (if you ran this on the column from a dataframe) do exactly that? I assumed the OP understood how to manipulate columns and rows in a DataFrame, that they only needed help with text pattern matching.

Comment: " retaining the dataframe structure as well." I read this as bringing the results back into dataframe--not printing, per the last line you provided.

Comment: Indeed, but I was just sharing the critical piece that the @Basudev needed, not trying to correct their code. "Teach a person to fish..." style. Basudev already knows how to handle DataFrames. And they know best exactly how they'd like to do that for their app (column name, index, row order, etc).